# how to set the item values in page header oracle apex

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have 2 Item from date and to date and one submit button in a page..

:p1_enter_start_date and :p1_enter_end_date and one Submit button

In that user have to enter the from and to dates to get the output report region as intractive report.

Now i want to show the from and two dates in that page header which user have selected, that will be captured in items

please suggest how to set the item values to page header in oracle apex page

Answer (score 1):

You can display the value of an item as html using the &ITEM. notation. So in your case that would be &P1_ENTER_START_DATE. and &P1_ENTER_END_DATE. (Don't forget the trailing .). You can check the documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/htmdb/understanding-page-level-items.html